# Minikube default CPU/Memory

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to determine the default CPU and memory allocation for Minikube (version > 1.0).

When running the following:

```
$ minikube config get memory && minikube config get cpu
Error: specified key could not be found in config
```

values are not returned unless explicitly set with the `--cpus` and `--memory` options.

Comment: It would also be ```minikube config get cpus```, use ```minikube config options``` for a list of the correct names.

Comment: Though previously the default Minikube CPU and memory allocation was set to a reasonable default (see: [Version 0.12.0 - 10/21/2016](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-0120---10212016)) if not specified, the CPUs and memory are calculated given the system information.

For reference, see [`cmd/minikube/cmd/start.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/cmd/minikube/cmd/start.go).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default memory constant is `2048` (megabytes) as seen [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/232080ae0cbcf9cb9a388eb76cc11cf6884e19c0/pkg/minikube/constants/constants.go#L102).

This doesn't automatically change with the vm-driver.

Answer (score 25):

The default memory limit is 2GB and the CPU limit is 2. You can see the current config with the following command:

**Altogether;**

```
~ ❯ minikube config view vm-driver
- cpus: 4
- memory: 16384
```

**Each one;**

```
~ ❯ minikube config get memory                                          ✘ INT
16384

~ ❯ minikube config get cpus
4
```

Also, you can set default CPU and memory before starting the minikube:

```
minikube config set cpus 4
minikube config set memory 16384
```

❗ Do not forget, if you have already a minikube cluster you need to delete the minikube by executing **minikube delete** command and then executing **minikube start** command.

Comment: This answer is excellent.  I just wanted to know the defaults, but this gave me all the info I needed, thank you for this!

Answer (score 12):

Default Minikube cluster CPU is **`2`**

Default Minikube cluster memory is **`2048`**

```
minikube config get cpus
minikube config get memory
```

---

**Note:**
`cat ~/.minikube/config/config.json` won't be displaying the details until you manually configure it

Comment: just use minikube config set cpus 4 minikube config set memory 8192 to set it

Comment: I get `Error: specified key could not be found in config` when running those commands

Answer (score 2):

This probably only makes sense for OSX / windows users.

If you are running minikube on Virtualbox you can open Virtualbox, right click on minikube's image then close > power off. Once the VM is turned off you can then go in Settings > System and modify the default memory allocated to minikube (which seems to be 4GB).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using vagrant to create your linux (Ubuntu) instance, default memory allocation to newly created linux instance would be around 1GB, but Minikube need minimum 2 GB to run.

simple hack is shut down your VM instance, go to settings and increase the memory size (3GB preferred - 1GB for OS 2GB for Minikube) and now try running your instance and Minikube start.